# ACL-based API Permissions in Servicestack

Tags: c#, servicestack

**Situation:**
I am coding a service application for my company and since fixed roles are not suitable in my case I want to establish ACL based access to my API services.
The model and the database side are not my problem.
**Question:**
How would I relaize a Request Filter that runs after Authentication (JWT and Credentials) but before my services (Get, Post,...) which determines if the user is allowed to call that action (in this filter I would check my ACLs and return allowed or refused).
I don't need a turnkey solution but suggestions are very welcome!
**Details:** Roles and User don't exist at implementation time. In my Frontend I want to create roles and users (like Windows or similar) and assign rights dynmically. Rights of roles and users could change. Even roles couldbe deleted and replaced by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you just want to [validate permissions](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#requiredrole-and-requiredpermission-attributes) so I'd use the built-in `[RequiredPermission]` or `[RequiresAnyPermission]` attributes if it fits your use-case.

Otherwise my preferred approach would be to implement any ACL's using a declarative [Request Filter Attribute](https://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) which is also how the built-in [AuthenticateAttribute.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs) are implemented but with a negative `Priority` so they will be executed before any custom Filter Attributes which by default have a `Priority=0`.

Comment: To which Priority  do I have to set "my filter" to ensure that it runs "after" authentication? I want to use the built-in authentication.

Comment: @ElChipo you can set in the constructor, but you don’t need to because the AuthFilters already have a -Priority and will run before your filter attributes

Comment: How do I access the payload of the bearer token in Request or Reponse Filters? I can't any conrete examples about how to access the payload anywhere. I have populated my JWT but don't know how to get the data.

Comment: @ElChipo please open a new question for different questions, you can access the request info from IRequest, what to use depends on how it’s populated, please show how the JWT is populated in your new question